# How does one make and use temporal joins of CSV files in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, spatio-temporal-data

I have two CSV files, one with spatial information, and one with temporal information, to be joined on `id`

It looks like there are several methods,

1. Layer/Add Layer/Add Vector Layer of both CSVs (or .vrts of .csvs) and then do a Properties/Join on the spatial layer to make an in-memory layer
2. Use MMQGIS/Combine/Attributes join from CSV file to make on-disk layer
3. Use processing/Vector General/Join attributes by field value

Samples of my files are like:

```
 station_in_gis.csv: 222 stations:

"lon","lat","id","x","y","z","note"
-76.11299003247764,36.96681296908706,1,97289.70404745551,4115155.18968458,0.0,"    !CBBT"
-75.98798724775321,37.165139869138926,2,110001.7354024933,4137233.7577695996,0.0,"    !Kipp"
...

staout_melted.csv: 220 stations x 166 times = 36852 rows

"id","secs","valid_time","elev"
1,1800.0,"2020-10-22 00:30:00",0.0186178
1,3600.0,"2020-10-22 01:00:00",0.051513800000000005
1,5400.0,"2020-10-22 01:30:00",0.0897535
1,7200.0,"2020-10-22 02:00:00",0.124426
1,9000.0,"2020-10-22 02:30:00",0.198678
1,10800.0,"2020-10-22 03:00:00",0.292794
1,12600.0,"2020-10-22 03:30:00",0.40008499999999997
1,14400.0,"2020-10-22 04:00:00",0.497468
1,16200.0,"2020-10-22 04:30:00",0.5340550000000001
2,1800.0,"2020-10-22 00:30:00",-0.036708199999999996
2,3600.0,"2020-10-22 01:00:00",0.000558725
2,5400.0,"2020-10-22 01:30:00",0.0470811
2,7200.0,"2020-10-22 02:00:00",0.08760880000000001
2,9000.0,"2020-10-22 02:30:00",0.148671
2,10800.0,"2020-10-22 03:00:00",0.23444600000000002
2,12600.0,"2020-10-22 03:30:00",0.33513699999999996
2,14400.0,"2020-10-22 04:00:00",0.44592600000000004
2,16200.0,"2020-10-22 04:30:00",0.512962
2,18000.0,"2020-10-22 05:00:00",0.548772
...
```

I did write a couple .vrt files:

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="staout_melted">
        <SrcDataSource relativeToVRT="1">staout_melted.csv</SrcDataSource>
        <Field name="id"  type="String"/>
        <Field name="secs"  type="Real"/>
        <Field name="valid_time"  type="DateTime" />
        <Field name="elev" type="Real" />
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>




<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="station_in_gis">
        <SrcDataSource relativeToVRT="1">station_in_gis.csv</SrcDataSource>
        <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
        <LayerSRS>WGS84</LayerSRS>
        <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="lon" y="lat" />
        <Field name="lon" type="Real" />
        <Field name="lat" type="Real" />
        <Field name="id"  type="String"/>
        <Field name="x"  type="Real"/>
        <Field name="y" type="Real" />
        <Field name="z" type="Real" />
        <Field name="note"  type="String" />

    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

What I would like to do is join these two together and end up with a layer that ends up time aware, ultimately enabling one to color points by `elev` scanning across time with the temporal control or click-to-ID station `1` (CBBT) at `2020-10-22 03:30:00` as having `elev=0.4000`

What steps do I need to do to:

1. Get the CSV files into QGIS as a time-aware joined layer?
2. Use the Temporal Controller and id to get the temporally-varied `elev`?
3. Make the symbology use this time-sensitive `elev` data?

I've tried MMQGIS and the Layer/Properties/Join, but an `id` on a point only  seems to get one time stamp, and enabling the temporal controller seems to make the points vanish.  I think I've not joined properly.

---

With MMQGIS, I can use the .vrt file on the spatial file before the join, but MMQGIS doesn't seem to join .vrt, just CSVs, so I can't control the field types, in particular, the valid_time field.  I do end up with a large inner join with 36582 spatio-temporal observations, but without temporal awareness.

With the layer/properties/join, I seem only to get my 222 stations with one single timestamp.

---

From the comments:

I tried a join external to QGIS using the csvkit's `csvjoin` with a `csvjoin -c id -u 0 station_in_gis.csv staout_melted.csv  >csvjoined_schism.csv` command, and, with a .vrt file this makes it into what seems to be a temporally compatible file. At the layer level I can `Properties/Temporal/Single field` with date/time and I get a clock icon on the layer. I can then `Project/Properties/Temporal/Calculate` from Layers and it sets temporal extents. But under the 'id' tool each point has multiple ids, one for each timestamp. Am I doing this right?

I'm able to make a Virtual layer join with `/Layer/Create Layer/Add Virtual Layer` on my tables with a `SELECT * FROM station_in_gis, staout_melted where station_in_gis.id=staout_melted.id` However, I can't set temporal on that layer's valid_time field though. I think I'll need a richer SQL for the join. (it would be nice if you could recover or edit the SQL from the virtual table's properties...You can with right-click on the layer and `Edit Virtual Layer`)

`SELECT lon,lat,station_in_gis.id as id_0, staout_melted.id as id_1, valid_time /*:DateTime*/,elev, station_in_gis.geometry FROM station_in_gis, staout_melted where station_in_gis.id = staout_melted.id` seems to work to Join, in `Layer/Create Layer/Add Virtual Layer` as shown in the screenshot below, but the `valid_time` columns remains stubbornly a String field.

[image: Create Virtual Layer screenshot]

Comment: I tried a join external to QGIS using the csvkit's `csvjoin` with a `csvjoin -c id -u 0 station_in_gis.csv staout_melted.csv  >csvjoined_schism.csv` command, and, with a `.vrt` file this makes it into what seems to be a temporally compatible file.  At the layer level I can `Properties/Temporal/Single field with date/time` and I get a clock icon on the layer.  I can then `Project/Properties/Temporal/Calculate from Layers` and it sets temporal extents.  But under the 'id' tool each point has multiple ids, one for each timestamp.  Am I doing this right?

Comment: I'm able to make a Virtual layer join with `/Layer/Create Layer/Add Virtual Layer` on my tables with a `SELECT * FROM station_in_gis, staout_melted where station_in_gis.id=staout_melted.id`.  I can't set temporal on that layer's `valid_time` field though.

Comment: I see that within QGIS 3.14, I can work around text-format DateTime attributes with Expressions.  Under `Layer/Properties/Temporal` you can apply an expression to a field to get the temporal timestamps with `Temporal/Start and End Date/Time from Expressions` with, for example `to_datetime( valid_time)-make_interval(minutes:=15)` and `to_datetime( valid_time)+make_interval(minutes:=15)`

Answer (score 3):

The best performance seems to be that one can join spatial and temporal CSV files outside of QGIS with a database program or `csvkit`'s csvjoin:

```
 csvjoin -c id -u 0 station_in_gis.csv staout_melted.csv > csvjoined_schism.csv
```

with a .vrt file:

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="csvjoined_schism">
        <SrcDataSource relativeToVRT="1">csvjoined_schism.csv</SrcDataSource>
        <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
        <LayerSRS>WGS84</LayerSRS>
        <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="lon" y="lat" />
        <Field name="lon" type="Real" />
        <Field name="lat" type="Real" />
        <Field name="id"  type="String"/>
        <Field name="x"  type="Real"/>
        <Field name="y" type="Real" />
        <Field name="z" type="Real" />
        <Field name="secs"  type="Real"/>
        <Field name="valid_time"  type="DateTime" />
        <Field name="elev" type="Real" />
        <Field name="note"  type="String" />

    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

This makes it into a temporally compatible file.  At the layer level you can `Properties/Temporal/Single field with date/time` and get a clock icon on the layer overview. You can then `Project/Properties/Temporal/Calculate from Layers` and it sets temporal extents of the project to match the layers.

The symbology can be set as normal, but by using the 'Data Driven Override` boxes to the right of the symbology-defining fields, you can make the symbology vary with time.

[image]

[image]

Another way is to add the spatially aware CSV file and the temporally aware VRT file as separate layers using their VRT files, and then join the files with `/Layer/Create Layer/Add Virtual Layer/` with SQL like:

```
SELECT lon,lat,station_in_gis.id as id_0, staout_melted.id as id_1, valid_time ,elev, station_in_gis.geometry FROM station_in_gis, staout_melted where station_in_gis.id = staout_melted.id
```

...but virtual layers use SQLITE and do not represent DateTime fields.  You can work around this by using expressions with the for the temporal information. Under `Layer/Properties/Temporal` you can apply an expression to a field to get the temporal timestamps with `Temporal/Start and End Date/Time from Expressions` with, for example `to_datetime( valid_time)-make_interval(minutes:=15)` and `to_datetime( valid_time)+make_interval(minutes:=15)`:

The virtual join seems to work, but the performance seems to be slow compared to the externally-joined table.

[image]